# Dsolve diff. and sin function as symbolic equation

Tags: matlab, symbols, differential-equations, equation-solving, dsolve

I am looking for a way to solve the following differential equation by MATLAB:

```
Y=-acc*h*cos(t) + g*h*sin(t) - gama*T.'*H*cos(t)-I0*diff(t,2)
X=solve(Y==0,t)
```

and the parameters defined as:

```
g=9.81; c=0.03; w=0.05; acc=0.5*g; gama=0.05;
syms  t(x) h b H1 H2
H=[H1; H2];
R=sqrt(b^2+h^2);
I0=R^2*( (1/3) +(h/R)^2 );
u=H*sin(t);
udot=diff(u);
udotdot=diff(u,2);
T=udotdot+[1; 1]*acc+2*c*w*udot+w^2*u;
```

But I can't find any solution dor 't'.
Does anyone has any idea how to do such things?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: In all probability there is no such solution in symbolic terms. In general, for every problem that can be solved symbolically there is an infinity of close-by problems that do not have such a solution. -- As the second order derivative appears in two places, it would also take some effort to prepare this problem for a numerical solver.

Comment: That said, maybe you should ask on math.stackexchange if someone has an idea how to solve this differential equation analytically. If that is what you need, it is not really a Matlab question.